# How to get cookie with path in laravel

Tags: cookies, laravel

I created a cookies is "myCart" in file `.js` with angular (I see this cookies in setting of chrome), the cookies saved with path "abc/def".

In controller file of Laravel, when I want to get value of this cookies I call
`$cookies = Cookie::get();` but `$cookies` haven't got "myCart".

How can I get cookie with path "abc/def" in Laravel?

Answer (score 0):

```
$cookies = Cookie::get('cookie_name');
```

Comment: Thank for your help but $cookies = Cookie::get(); to get all cookies but haven't myCart. $cookies = Cookie::get('myCart') => NULL!!!